# How to move an animated lottie JSON file in flutter in a straight line from one side of the screen to another

Tags: android, flutter, animation, after-effects, lottie

I would like to make a flutter App with animated characters to move like in this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qW-KIjHjjHM&t=5s

For the animated character, I used after effects and exported as JSON file to use as Lottie.

I want a blank screen and move the animated character across the screen and off the screen. Then again enter and follow a straight path. Each path is straight and the start and endpoint of the straight path are random just like the video.

What can I use to achieve something like this? I don't want full code just point me to something close to this, documentation, or anything which would help me achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the Lottie for flutter package, by adding the package below under your dependencies in pubspec.yaml

```
      lottie: ^0.7.0+1
```

2. Using Lottie animations in flutter is achieved with the Lottie Widget, it loads the json animation, from local file asset (Lottie.asset), remote url (Lottie.network) or zip file (Lottie.asset).

```
      //loads from file assets
      Lottie.asset(
       'assets/programming.json',
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
```

It works on my code.

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand, you can create the complete animation that you are talking about in Adobe aftereffects and then export the BodyMovin json file.
Once you've exported the json file, you can go to http://rive.app/ and import your json and there. After importing you can just export the .`flr` file and use it in your flutter app.

For more information check here https://twitter.com/rive_app/status/1169294765625618432?s=20

Lastly you can use the repeat feature to play the animation infinitely.

Comment: You have understood the process well sir. My knowledge is limited to how I would move json file on the flutter screen. I am aware of the animation translate feature of flutter but I would also have to rotate the animation to face the direction it is going to move. Which function can I use for the animation to automatically determine rotation angle it requires to match the straight path. As the paths are random throughout the screen, the rotation should match for each path.